# No stable solution using metaMDS() in Vegan

Tags: r, vegan

I have a species abundance dataset with quite a few zeros in it and even when I set `trymax = 1000` for `metaMDS()` the program is unable to find a stable solution for the stress. I have already tried combining data (collapsing multiple years together to reduce the number of zeros) and I can't do any more. I was just wondering if anyone knows - is it scientifically valid to pick what R gives me at the end (the lowest of the 1000 solutions) or should I not be using NMDS because it cannot find a stable spot? There seems to be very little information about this on the internet.

Comment: I think this is not a programming question. You should try your luck on crossvalidated.com or r-sig-eco mailing list.

Comment: Darn, I basically tossed a coin trying to decide if this was programming or vegan specific. I was afraid cross validated would tell me that this was a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One explanation for this is that you are trying to use too few dimensions for the mapping. I presume you are using the default `k = 2`? If so, try `k = 3` and compare the stress from the *best* solution you got from the 1000 tries for the `k = 2` solution.

I would be a little concerned to take one solution out of 1000 just because it had the best/lowest stress.

You could also try 1000 more random starts and see if it converges if you run more iterations. When you saved the output from `metaMDS()`, you can supply that object to another call to `metaMDS()` via the `previous.best` argument. It will then do `trymax` further random starts but compare any lower-stress solutions with the previous best and converge if it finds one similar to it, rather than have to find two similar low-stress solutions in the 1000 starts.

Comment: Thank you Gavin, those are great suggestions. I'll give them a shot later today when I can.

Comment: Hi Gavin, just wanted to follow up - my problem was too many sites that had no species in common. I used noshare=0.1 and it fixed the problem. I don't know if closed questions get deleted or live on but I thought it might be helpful in case anyone else ever sees this.