# If NMDS (vegan) convergence is impossible does that make the output useless?

Tags: output, vegan, convergence

Maybe this question is not in the right place and if so, I'll delete it.

Probably a very basic question: If NMDS (vegan package) convergence does not reach a solution (regardless of dimensions and iterations) does that make the output meaningless?

Because R does give an output. With a nice low stress level, good plot. All of that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to change the number of dimensions (`k = 3` or more), but display only the two first dimensions.

Some dataset are too complex to reach a solution in a 2d space. Even after `trymax=100000` one of my 'sp x site' dataset did not reached a solution. However, the stress kept consistently low in all iterations, then I assumed that no best solution was possible. Maybe after billions of iterations.

see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14437200/14708092

Answer (score 1):

There is no sufficient information in this question. So the answer is "it depends". Please give us a reproducible example.